# Downloading an exe without asking for administrator privileges C#

Tags: c#, .net

For the .NET Framework program I'm working on, I have an automatic updater set-up. It downloads a 7-zip Self-Extracting archive (in the form of an exe) from the latest github release, and runs it to update the program. The issue is, despite the fact that the program doesn't get installed anywhere that requires administrator privileges, the Update.exe always requires an admin to run it once installed, despite not being necessary when downloading it via browser. Is there any way to prevent this? Here's my current setup:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    // Add the user agent header, otherwise we will get access denied.
    client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");

    // Full asset streamed into a single string. I.E: https://github.com/soopercool101/BrawlCrate/releases/download/BrawlCrate_v0.14_Hotfix2/BrawlCrate.v0.14.6873.39137.exe
    string html = client.DownloadString(Asset.Url);
    client.DownloadFile(URL, AppPath + "/Update.exe"); // AppPath is defined as whereever the program is installed
}
```

Comment: Check whether Update.exe has a manifest that tells Windows whether it needs admin permissions. If it doesn't, Windows will have to guess, and the filename "Update.exe" alone will cause Windows to guess that admin permissions may be required.

Comment: Agreed with Daniel, check out the file, Project => Properties => app.manifest, => Security => requestedExecutionLevel

Comment: Daniel, thank you so much! Naming it "temp.exe" instead causes it to correctly not require admin privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As according to Daniel, it was the name "update.exe" that was causing Windows to assume it needed admin privileges. Downloading it as "temp.exe" instead causes it to no longer prompt for admin approval.